# Setting the name of an uploaded image in Laravel-admin by using the model

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-admin

I tried the following code:

```
$form->image('image', 'Image')->name($form->model()->title."_".$form->model()->id.".jpg");
```

The result is just a file named `_.jpg`, and I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Of course, I want to keep even the file default extension if possible, but how you can see, I failed at it.

Comment: by `$form->model()` you're retrieving a Builder instance, what you need is your model though. So either eager load it by `$form->model` or execute a new query by `$form->model()->get()`... But lazy loading is preferable though.

Comment: Using first method I get `Trying to get property 'title' of non-object`, and using second I get `Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.`.

Comment: Then something's wrong with your relations. This means that `model` is null for some reason. You should check out what's going on behind the scenes... do some debugging on that.